# How to create a facebook notifcation header bar ?

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook-graph-api, user-interface

I'm trying to understard what are necessary  tools to get notifications from DB in push style. 
A facebook or stackoverflow itself could be a great style to follow :D

1 -How does the comunication beetween browser and DB works?
2- How  the can I refresh only a single part of page without refreshing  all page?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Your question is way to general to answer well, what have you tried so far? what problems are you running into? By the looks of your tags you already know that AJAX is you answer to refreshing a single part of a html page.. I would also look into SignalR for reverse AJAX which will give you your 'push' style of notification rather than polling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for what's commonly referred to as a Growl.  They come in all shapes and sizes and there are quite a few different ways to implement them.  Here's a few that I've learned from:

[Eric Hynds JQuery UI Notification Widget](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-notify/)

[jGrowl](http://stanlemon.net/pages/jgrowl)

[Stack Overflow Style Notification Bar](http://blog.nerdstogeeks.com/2011/01/create-stackoverflow-kind-of.html)

As for triggering the notification, firing it on load and then doing [Long Polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103490/ajax-long-polling) is probably an effective method to ensure it works.  In my apps, I build a "growler" function that I do both of the above AND fire on completion of certain events...once together, it all functions well, being both responsive AND timely.

Finally, to only refresh a single portion of the page, you'd simply inner HTML or change the value via Javascript after your ajax calls.  There's a million jQuery content replacement tutorials that will guide you on your way.