# ajax request and activity in browser console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I was checking my website activity by opening console in chrome and there was nasty ajax activity.. but when I checked the stackoverflow and facebook console in chrome there was no activity .. No I am wondering what are they doing to make ajax request why is there no activity for them..

Comment: Just wait a while and you'll see them

Comment: Yes, wait for a while and you'll see them. facebook do uses polling.

Comment: No dear there things are really quiet.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called Polling. It is called Push Technology, where the server pushes the code from it to the web page. This can be done through web sockets.

Few related things could be:

- [Push Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)
- [What is Long Polling](http://www.quora.com/What-is-long-polling-in-a-web-framework)
- [Ajax Long Polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103490/ajax-long-polling)
- [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))
- [How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)

Comment: +1 for sontha dabba :)

Comment: Thanks... did not hear about this before..

Comment: Check out the related terms. Also, google for [`faye`](http://faye.jcoglan.com/). @AzamKhan.

Comment: is it ok if I am using ajax requests and that shows fussy activity.. seems very immature though.

Comment: Generally newbies do that. Even I do that. Nothing wrong. Only problem would be, you will be requesting the server and if there are more number of users, and simultaneous requests go to the server, it cannot handle.

Comment: Please tell me book names on this topic separate articles make no sense

Comment: Ah.. You need to go by google, not by books. That's my suggestion.

Comment: ok... though difficult... give me your facebook link..