# Best way to get status when Iron.io task is completed using Laravel 4 queues

Tags: queue, laravel, laravel-4, message-queue, iron.io

I am going to use Laravel 4 queues and integrate them with Iron.io
All of that is pretty straight forward, and I dont think I am going to have problems with that.

Thing that interests me is what is the best way to get status once task is completed?

Iron.io is going to do return call to my server to trigger job, and once that job completes I need to notify user about that...

How could I store this responses, and still be aware of job its related to, because there will be number of different job types?

I would like to hear how did you implement this.

Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't your job handler send the email?

Comment: I want to have on page notification if possible. Its more user friendly

Comment: You'll have to either use [websockets](http://socketo.me/), or store it in a database and use [(long?) polling](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDgJF77jELo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Joseph pointed out in the comments, you'll need to:

1. Hopefully have a job quick enough for it to be finished when a user is still in browser
2. Use some sort of way to PUSH data back to your web browser.

The popular methods are:

1. [Websockets](http://socket.io/)
2. [Server-sent events](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)
3. [Long polling - with ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103490/ajax-long-polling)

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I am new to all this and wanted to know best way to do this.
Fideloper: I was actually learning about queues from your blog "Production-Ready Beanstalkd with Laravel 4 Queues". Great read!!